# timer function with interval parameter in python

Tags: python

I call static function of the class and expected it will run per 3 seconds and only 5 times.. But it's not stop at counter =5, goes on running
I searched and found sys.exit(0) can stop the timer. Whats wrong with it ?

```
def senLogtoBackup():
  threading.Timer(3, senLogtoBackup).start()
  AccessLog.AccessLog.backupAccessLog("logbackups","example.log")

try:
    senLogtoBackup()
    if AccessLog.AccessLog.Counter == 5:
        sys.exit(0) # expects I it will terminate the timer. but it still counts
```

Class definition:

```
class AccessLog:
        Counter =0
        @staticmethod
        def backupAccessLog(target, source):
            AccessLog.Counter+=1
            print "counter",AccessLog.Counter
```

Comment: I really wonder why did unvote ? anything wrong with question or u have problem something personal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you searched wrong, take a look at [os._exit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os._exit)

you should use "t.cancel" to stop timer.